# Ajax php frameworks

Tags: php, ajax, frameworks

Are there any good php ajax frameworks out there that make it easier to use ajax? Im new to ajax and it would be great to have a framework that could ease the development.

Answer (score 0):

JAX is a good choice. but you can try researching a bit to suit your needs i.e. your preference of programming language.

I believe the following link will help you too: http://ajaxpatterns.org/PHP_Ajax_Frameworks